# Tab background isn't showing when using columns inside tab

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

i'm using bootstrap tab and i want to divide this tab with bootstrap grid system but because of the `float:left;` , tabs background not showing.

here is my code;

```
<div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane fade in active" id="home">
        <div class="col-lg-6">
          <h3>Categories</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-6" >
          <h3>Datasets</h3>
        </div>
    </div>
```

if i don't add this `col-lg-6` classes it is working properly , thank you for your suggestions

**Fixed Code**; (just added row class before grid classes)

```
<div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane fade in active" id="home">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-6">
          <h3>Categories</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-6" >
          <h3>Datasets</h3>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing at what the actual problem is, but you almost always want to wrap columns in a row element.

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-6">
         <h3>Categories</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-6">
         <h3>Datasets</h3>
    </div>
</div>
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/isherwood/kqphbkby/)**

The row element forces the tab element to clear the floated columns. If you already have a row element outside the tab panes, either move it inside or add a full-width column outside and a row inside.

Fiddle updated with tab color.